# How to convert object datatype column that uses a hyphen to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

How to convert this object datatype column with only two type of entries being read as date (4-Jan and 14-May) because they use a hyphen. Other values in the values don't convert into a date format and are working fine.

[image: Spreadsheet-Sample]

Comment: What is the code you're using to create the dataframe?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to match a number followed by hyphen and a month name. Then use a date parsing function to convert it to to a date.